# Doc2Vec Pre training and Inferring vectors

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding, doc2vec, pre-trained-model

Suppose I have trained the doc2vec model with 50000 documents and I want to infer vectors for a separate dataset containing 36000 documents. In this case will the inferred vectors be effective for the downstream task of classification, becasue my assumption is that the inferred vectors depend on the size of documents with which the model is trained.

Note: Both dataset i.e one used for training doc2vec and other for inferring vectors are unique but from the same domain of US supreme court.

Please correct me if I am wrong with valid reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a tiny dataset, no answer I can give will be as useful as just trying it to see if it works.

50000 is smallish for a training set, but some useful `Doc2Vec` results have been based on similar corpuses.

Vector inference, like training, reduces documents of any length to a fixed-size vector. (But note: gensim silently limits any text fed to a `2Vec` model to 10000 tokens.)

But, if you've trained a model on documents that are all about 1000 words, then try inference on 10-word fragments, those doc-vectors might not be as useful, or useful in the same way, as inferred vectors on documents more similar to the training set. But you'd still need to try it to find out. (Also note: words not learned during training are completely ignored during inference, so later inferences on docs with many/all unknown words will be weak or meaningless.)

Is that the the case with your inference docs – they are very different from training docs in size & vocabulary? And if so, why? (Can you train with more representative documents?)

If the set of 36000 documents is fixed before training begins, it may also be valid/defensible to include them in the unsupervised `Doc2Vec` training. They're data, they help learn the domain lingo, and they don't have in them any form of the "right" answers for classification.

Comment: Thank you for your warnings and I will take care of it with higher priority. One clarification needed on the last para, is it technically correct to feed the documents for which I am going to infer vectors during unsupervised doc2vec training. I see you have stated that it is valid to include the 36000 documents during the training as the model will learn the domain vocabulary and they dont possess any form of decision about the labels. Is it not a kind of cheating with the model ? Can you kindly stress a little more on this reasoning. @gojomo

Comment: It depends on your specific goals. Are the 36k docs just one trial batch, and you want your estimates of the systems' accuracy/etc to be fairly reliable about how it will, from a frozen model, continue to work on future similar batches? Getting that accurate estimate could justify holding back data from unsupervised training. But if classifying the 36k are the final goal, what you want is best performance, not theoretically-unbiased estimates of future performance.

Comment: Or if every time another N-thousand docs arrive, you legitimately could retrain-everything, so your real in-production system will be able to learn more about the domain (unsupervised) from not-yet-classified docs, then again, it could be valid to use them as part of the unsupervised step. For comparison, this is what the original 'Paragraph Vector' (aka `Doc2Vec`) paper did in its experiment on IMDB review sentiments. (Section 3.1 of <https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf>.)